# Simpe Android JUnit test hangs in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, unit-testing, junit

I've been following book about Android testing and implemented this sample:

```
public class TemperatureConverterActivityTests extends
        ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<TemperatureConverterActivity> {

    private TemperatureConverterActivity mActivity;

    private EditText mCelsius;
    private EditText mFarenheit;

    public TemperatureConverterActivityTests() {
        this("TemperatureConverterActivityTests");
    }

    public TemperatureConverterActivityTests(String name) {
        super(TemperatureConverterActivity.class);
        setName(name);
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        mActivity = getActivity();

        mCelsius = (EditText) mActivity
                .findViewById(org.mighter.tc.R.id.celsius);
        mFarenheit = (EditText) mActivity
                .findViewById(org.mighter.tc.R.id.farenheit);
    }

    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    public final void testPreconditions() {
        assertNotNull(mActivity);
    }

    public final void testHasInputFields() {
        assertNotNull(mCelsius);
        assertNotNull(mFarenheit);
    }

}
```

However, test doesn't finish.

What I get in the Console:

```
Android Launch!
adb is running normally.
Performing android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner JUnit launch
Automatic Target Mode: Several compatible targets. Please select a target device.
Uploading TemperatureConverterTest.apk onto device '80A358103041548074'
Installing TemperatureConverterTest.apk...
Success!
Project dependency found, installing: TemperatureConverter
Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
Launching instrumentation android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on device 80A358103041548074
Collecting test information
Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'
Test run finished
Sending test information to Eclipse
Running tests...
```

And then it hangs, here's JUnit view:

[image]

The only info from LogCat:

```
05-28 17:23:54.952: W/ActivityManager(224): Crash of app org.mighter.tc running instrumentation ComponentInfo{org.mighter.tc.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
05-28 17:23:55.042: I/TestRunner(7174): <!>android.test.TestPrinter 50<!> started: testHasInputFields(org.mighter.tc.test.TemperatureConverterActivityTests)
05-28 17:23:55.062: I/TestRunner(7174): <!>android.test.TestPrinter 56<!> finished: testHasInputFields(org.mighter.tc.test.TemperatureConverterActivityTests)
05-28 17:23:55.062: I/TestRunner(7174): <!>android.test.TestPrinter 77<!> passed: testHasInputFields(org.mighter.tc.test.TemperatureConverterActivityTests)
05-28 17:23:55.072: I/TestRunner(7174): <!>android.test.TestPrinter 50<!> started: testPreconditions(org.mighter.tc.test.TemperatureConverterActivityTests)
05-28 17:23:55.082: I/TestRunner(7174): <!>android.test.TestPrinter 56<!> finished: testPreconditions(org.mighter.tc.test.TemperatureConverterActivityTests)
05-28 17:23:55.082: I/TestRunner(7174): <!>android.test.TestPrinter 77<!> passed: testPreconditions(org.mighter.tc.test.TemperatureConverterActivityTests)
05-28 17:23:55.652: I/TestRunner(7194): <!>android.test.TestPrinter 50<!> started: testHasInputFields(org.mighter.tc.test.TemperatureConverterActivityTests)
05-28 17:23:55.853: I/TestRunner(7194): <!>android.test.TestPrinter 56<!> finished: testHasInputFields(org.mighter.tc.test.TemperatureConverterActivityTests)
05-28 17:23:55.853: I/TestRunner(7194): <!>android.test.TestPrinter 77<!> passed: testHasInputFields(org.mighter.tc.test.TemperatureConverterActivityTests)
05-28 17:23:55.853: I/TestRunner(7194): <!>android.test.TestPrinter 50<!> started: testPreconditions(org.mighter.tc.test.TemperatureConverterActivityTests)
```

Tried debugging, but it never reaches testPreconditions().
Thanks.

Comment: it could be hanging in setUp(), setUp is executed before each unit test method

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me to looking into code. I forgot to call super in tearDown();

Comment: I think you should post your tear down method as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just needed to call  super in tearDown();

Comment: Thank you! Must be the fragments or something that made me need super.tearDown() when the tutorial doesn't need it.